# Remove unmanaged symbols from C++/CLI assembly meta information

Tags: c++-cli

I have created a C++/CLI wrapper around some library. When I inspect the compiled assembly in one of the freely available decompilers, apart from pure managed classes and namespaces I see a plethora of unmanaged pure C++ classes and namespaces. I see no point in having them there.

Is there a way to get rid of them and show only pure managed stuff? This is a question of pure aesthetics, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would want to create an non-mixed assembly, then. Read up on [the different 'flavours' of C++/CLR libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85344whh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

- Mixed (/clr)
- Pure (/clr:pure)
- Safe (/clr:safe)

In particular, you seem to be after `/clr:safe` which is the most restrictive output format and results in assemblies, just as created with e.g. C# or VB.Net

[Mixed, Pure, and Verifiable Feature Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173252%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! When I try `/clr:safe` I get a bunch of warnings like this `error C4956: 'va_list *' : this type is not verifiable` and when I use `/clr:pure` I get these a lot `error C3862: '<snip>': cannot compile an unmanaged function with /clr:pure or /clr:safe`. AFAIK, since I am doing a wrapper I must use `/clr` but then I get a bunch of unwanted symbols.

Comment: @wpfwannabe: you might consider having an extra assembly layer: have a '/clr:safe' facade that delegates to the mixed-mode `/clr` assembly that implements the actual wrapper

Comment: I get it. Thanks! It's a bit cumbersome and the other assembly would still suffer from the same illness but it's better than nothing I suppose. I was hoping for a more straightforward solution like a compiler option but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It is a lot more than just esthetics, you are apparently compiling native code to IL instead of machine code.  The C++/CLI compiler is very good at compiling native C++ code to IL, almost anything is supported.  What you get is however inefficient, you don't get the benefit of the code optimizer that can take its merry time inside the compiler to generate optimized machine code.  The .NET just-in-time compiler has an optimizer too but it can't do quite the same job.

Fix this by applying the /clr option only to individual source code files.  Or you can do it in source code with the #pragma managed directive.

Comment: I remember using that #pragma some time ago. Thanks for reminding me. I have run some tests and regardless of me sprinkling `#pragma unmanaged` all over the place, my pure C++ classes still show in the decompiler. What's going on?